# Entity framework code first map multiple complex types of the same type to a table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, complextype

If you have the following domain model:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public TestB A { get; set; }
    public TestB B { get; set; }
    public TestB C { get; set; }

}

public class TestB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And you have a table with the following structure:

```
Test
 - Description
 - NameA
 - DescriptionA
 - NameB
 - DescriptionB
 - NameC
 - DescriptionC
```

Where the name and description pairs map to an individual instance of complex type B.

Is there any way of defining this mapping purely using the fluent APIs assuming the database schema cannot be changed?

The only way I have gotten this to work in a reasonable way is to derive subtypes of TestB and map them like this:

```
        modelBuilder.ComplexType<TestB>().Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("NameA");
        modelBuilder.ComplexType<TestB>().Property(x => x.Description).HasColumnName("DescriptionA");

        modelBuilder.ComplexType<TestB1>().Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("NameB");
        modelBuilder.ComplexType<TestB1>().Property(x => x.Description).HasColumnName("DescriptionB");
```

I'd rather not have to define derived types purely for the mappings to entity framework.