# EF 6.0 - Map complex type to same table as parent property

Tags: entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I have looked at the following:

[Entity framework code first map multiple complex types of the same type to a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066051/entity-framework-code-first-map-multiple-complex-types-of-the-same-type-to-a-tab)

Given the example code:

```
[Table("TXLifeRequest", Schema = "txlife")]
public partial class TXLifeRequest
{
    public virtual OLI_LU_BOOLEAN PendingResponseOK { get; set; }
    ...
}

[Table("OLI_LU_BOOLEAN", Schema = "txlife")]
public partial class OLI_LU_BOOLEAN {

    public string tc { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to structure the database so that the `OLI_LU_BOOLEAN` is not in a new table, rather to be two new columns in the `TXLifeRequest` table as something like `TXLifeRequest.PendingResponseOK_tc` and `PendingResponseOK _Value`.

There is no fluent code in the existing context.  Is there a way to do this either by fluent or attrubutes so that the class structure is intact but the tables are combined?

**Update:**

I have tried the following but it creates a new table `TXLifeRequest1` for all of the `OLI_LU_BOOLEAN` properties.  How would I specify these as properties of same table?

`modelBuilder.ComplexType<OLI_LU_BOOLEAN>()`

```
CreateTable("imsparamed.TXLifeRequest1",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    PendingResponseOK_Value = c.String(),
                    PendingResponseOK_Id = c.Int(nullable: false)

                })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create a complex type:

```
modelBuilder.ComplexType<OLI_LU_BOOLEAN>().Ignore(i => i.Value);
```